# Does hotspot connect directly to proxy or through the computer from the connection being shared?

Tags: windows, wifi-hotspot, proxy

Let's say I have connected my phone to the internet through the hotspot from my Laptop. In order to access the internet, i have to configure proxy in both laptop and android.
Now on the server side would the traffic come from my laptop or it would be shown as different i.e coming from the android?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why proxy set on Android does not work when used as hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209105/why-proxy-set-on-android-does-not-work-when-used-as-hotspot)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly your Laptop is the device that is connected to the Internet and it shares the connection to the phone. In this situation the proxy operator will see one IP address (the public IP from your Laptop, but the proxy client on phone and laptop will behave a little bit different and therefore it is not impossible to distinguish between both devices (or to detect that there are two different devices connected from the same IP).